# bundler: specify ruby version based on platform

Tags: ruby, bundler, jruby

We're doing some A/B testing on MRI vs JRuby for a microservice we've written.

I need my server or any local developer to use a specified version of JRuby or MRI.

I've read through [Bundler's docs](http://bundler.io/v1.7/man/gemfile.5.html) and thought I understood the use of ruby engine's to be used like this:

```
platforms :jruby do
  ruby '1.9.3', engine: :jruby, engine_version: '1.7.19'
  gem 'bson'
end

platforms :ruby do
  ruby '2.2.0', engine: :ruby, engine_version: '2.2.0'
  gem 'bson_ext'
end
```

However if I do `$which ruby` I get: `.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.19/bin/ruby` and then run `bundle install` I get:

```
Your Ruby engine is jruby, but your Gemfile specified ruby
```

How can I use bundler with platforms to specify a ruby version specific to the platform the user/server is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of current `Bundler` you can not do that, since `:platforms` only apply to `gem` declarations ... closest thing you can get is a "runtime" decision logic based on which Ruby loads the *Gemfile* :

```
if defined? JRUBY_VERSION
  ruby '1.9.3', engine: :jruby, engine_version: '1.7.19'
else
  ruby '2.2.0', engine: :ruby, engine_version: '2.2.0'
end

platforms :jruby do
  gem 'bson'
end

platforms :ruby do
  gem 'bson_ext'
end
```

Comment: Thanks @kares.  When I run `bundle install` with MRI and  your changes, I get `Your Ruby engine is ruby, but your Gemfile specified ruby`.  If I switch to jruby, I get `Your Ruby engine is jruby, but your Gemfile specified jruby`

Comment: yes ... as said this is the closest you get - it's mostly good if you're on one Ruby mostly but than someone else is on another and Gemfile.lock is not commited.

Comment: Use only the bundler DSL, never Ruby conditionals in Gemfiles: it breaks things like `bundle package --all` because it writes Gemfile.lock that will be nondeterministically wrong depending on which platform `bundle install` first.

Comment: Bundler has a long history if being non-platform aware -> despite `platform:` declarations .lock created in one Ruby not always working in another. hopefully it works by now (not sure - would be good to know since which version if so). thus (working) 'hacks' such as these exist(ed) ... due Bundler not caring for multi-Ruby shops much for quite some time.